# Is it possible to change sRGB/Non-Color color space procedurally?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, color, procedural

All "Diffuse-Albedo-Color" need to be, or at least they would be in an sRgb color space (in my experience), inside the diffuse node.
On the contrary the other maps such as: Normal, Specular, Roughness, etc ...
They should be set to "Non-Color" in the nodes.

Now the question I ask is the following:
I would like to keep the sRgb color space, and create a group that transforms (Or at least simulates) this "Non-Color" color space.
Is it possible to reproduce a procedural transformation after the 'TEX_IMAGE' node? The group would be immediately after the image and would serve to transform it into Non-Color

I'm not sure about this, and I'm not even sure if it requires additional hardware consumption.

Comment: I know the other way around if you want to know (noncolor to almost as same as srgb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can switch between Linear/sRGB color space with a Gamma node.
<sub>I learned it from [this Andy Burrows' article](https://www.creativeshrimp.com/normal-map-blender-tutorial.html#Problem2). No idea how it works though :)</sub>

1. Use Gamma: 0,454 to transform *sRGB* to *Non-Color*
2. Use Gamma: 2,200 to transform *Non-Color* to *sRGB*

[image]

Comment: If anyone could explain the principle behind it, I'd be happy to edit it in :).

Comment: Note: This is slightly inaccurate, and we need a proper *RGB>Linear* shader node https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/k225