# Is it wrong to use Metal-Roughness-Specular etc. maps in sRGB mode?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I think this "Non-Color" procedure to be set in the "Normal Map" image node is necessary in most cases (Except for any maps in different color space)
I understand 100% regarding the use of "Normal Map" and have done my tests to really check what happens.

But I am wondering if it is really necessary to set "Non-Color" space on the Black / White maps for the texture nodes "Metal", "Roughness", "Specular" etc.

I usually use jpg and png textures.
This question has been on my mind for a long time, even though I see that pretty much Everywhere I look, on any tutorial, "Non-Color" is set.

Comment: Hello :). It's not wrong in any way, just the colors will be shifted a bit. Normal maps will be affected more, since they use all three channnels.

Comment: Related: [Is possible simulate Non-Color Image with procedural nodes, from an sRGB image into Shader Editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214611/78972).

Comment: Hello @JachymMichal , sure, but I'm trying to understand, however, on types of maps not of the "Normal" type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically incorrect not to use the “non-color” color space you’re using is non-color, but the result will not be horribly incorrect. as another user said, values will be shifted a bit, and normal Maps the most because they use all three channels. But anyway, why do you not want to set this? There is thankfully a way to do it with the python API, as I’ve discovered when needing it for such a purpose.

Comment: Hi, I would like to point out that I am doing the example for maps not of the "Normal Map" type, therefore only "Black / White" maps. In any case it is more my curiosity, I do not have in mind not to use, but to understand why I have to do it in that way.

Comment: @NoobCat Well in that case, I think it would be best if you actually try it with SRGB instead of non-color and see what happens.