# Im new to blender and I'm having issues with colour differences in solid mode and render mode

Tags: rendering

[image]

[image]

In the pictures theres quite alot of difference in colour, is it an issue to do with light or material?

help ;-;

Comment: nvm found it its in colour management and filmic to standard

Comment: You may want to take a look at the comments under this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/222587/60486

Answer (score 0):

This is Eevee
It may have to do with the lighting and or HDRI viewport settings see pic

[image]

Comment: thank you I tried changing the engine to cycles aswell as changing the settings it's alot better but still not as vibrant as the one on the left, do you kno any fixes for that

Answer (score 0):

Might be lighting. In solid mode (depending on the settings used) colors can pop out more, which is why the material viewport is used for texturing and shading and such. You can try using a brighter light and use compositor or curves (under color management in render settings) to bring out the colors more.