# How can I change a specific color without repainting the entire object

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I have this dolphin and I only want to change the blue to another color. The eye and mouth are also painted on. Is there a way to adjust only the blue without painting over the eyes and white on the bottom?[image: a blue dolphin]

[image]

Comment: @moonboots method is easier, here, I think, but if you had a lot of color-switching to do, you could try something like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/222394/35559)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to automatically replace a color, but to avoid a meticulous repaint you could put a *Color > Hue/Saturation/Value* behind the *Image Texture* node and tweak the values:

[image]

Or do the same in an image editor app like Photoshop or Krita. In Krita it's in *Filter > Adjust > HSV* (Hue/Saturation/Lightness):

[image]