# Shader Editor: changing color space in one image texture node also changing another node? (2.92.0)

Tags: texturing, shaders, image, bump, shader-nodes

I'm editing a shader and I'm using one image texture node in the base color and another node to use as bump/normal.
I created both nodes independently (not duplicating), but in both I opened the same image file (it's a concrete texture that I want to use both as base color and as bump map).
However, even thouth I have two different nodes, whenever I change the one I'm using as bump map to "non-color" it also automatically changes the one in base color to non-color too. I noticed that if I use 2 different image files this doesn't happen. Is this a bug? Why can't I use the same image source as two different types of color space in different nodes?

[image: the color spaces of both nodes seem to be linked, if I change one the other one changes too]

*The color spaces of both nodes seem to be linked, if I change one the other one changes too*

Comment: Hello :). This is intended behavior - even though not very intuitive. You can either use duplicates of your image file or change it procedurally: [Is it possible to change sRGB/Non-Color color space procedurally?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214611/78972)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hope they change this in the future, though.